# pyinstaller\packaging_diif' not found

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyinstaller

Hello I am using pqt5 and I am unable to package using pysinatller. Can you please advise? Thank you.

C:\Python\Scripts\pyinstaller>pyinstaller --onefile packaging_diif between2num.py
425 INFO: PyInstaller: 6.1.0
425 INFO: Python: 3.9.7
455 INFO: Platform: Windows-10-10.0.19044-SP0
458 INFO: wrote C:\Python\Scripts\pyinstaller\packaging_diif.spec
script 'C:\Python\Scripts\pyinstaller\packaging_diif' not found

C:\Python\Scripts\pyinstaller>pip install pyinstaller
Requirement already satisfied: pyinstaller in c:\python\lib\site-packages (6.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools>=42.0.0 in c:\python\lib\site-packages (from pyinstaller) (57.4.0)
Requirement already satisfied: altgraph in c:\python\lib\site-packages (from pyinstaller) (0.17.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pyinstaller-hooks-contrib>=2021.4 in c:\python\lib\site-packages (from pyinstaller) (2023.10)
Requirement already satisfied: packaging>=20.0 in c:\python\lib\site-packages (from pyinstaller) (23.2)
Requirement already satisfied: importlib-metadata>=4.6 in c:\python\lib\site-packages (from pyinstaller) (6.8.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pefile>=2022.5.30 in c:\python\lib\site-packages (from pyinstaller) (2023.2.7)
Requirement already satisfied: pywin32-ctypes>=0.2.1 in c:\python\lib\site-packages (from pyinstaller) (0.2.2)
Requirement already satisfied: zipp>=0.5 in c:\python\lib\site-packages (from importlib-metadata>=4.6->pyinstaller) (3.17.0)

C:\Python\Scripts\pyinstaller>pyinstaller --onefile packaging_diif between2num.py
417 INFO: PyInstaller: 6.1.0
417 INFO: Python: 3.9.7
447 INFO: Platform: Windows-10-10.0.19044-SP0
449 INFO: wrote C:\Python\Scripts\pyinstaller\packaging_diif.spec
script 'C:\Python\Scripts\pyinstaller\packaging_diif' not found

I expected to see a .exe file with the pyinstaller converting

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.